# Xcode/lldb: stop application without symbols at entry into program

Tags: xcode, lldb

In lldb command line, I can stop execution of a program (which has no debug symbols) with the --stop-at-entry option by writing:

```
(lldb) target create /bin/ls
Current executable set to '/bin/ls' (x86_64).
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry
Process 22250 launched: '/bin/ls' (x86_64)
Process 22250 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xc46fa, 0x00007fff5fc01028 dyld`_dyld_start, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc01028 dyld`_dyld_start
dyld`_dyld_start:
-> 0x7fff5fc01028:  popq   %rdi
...
```

I would prefer, however, to work in the Xcode (5) IDE for lldb. Is the same thing possible there? I can successfully attach to a process through Menu Debug->Attach to Process-> By Process Identifier or Name. If you enter an application name there, lldb will take over that process as soon as it is launched. However, I see no way of stopping execution when the program starts up, i.e. the equivalent of  --start-at-entry. Nor do I see a way of entering the respective commands in the lldb window within the IDE, as the application is not launched yet.

Is this possible in the IDE?

Comment: No I don't think that is possible as Xcode is really intended for debugging an app that you are developing, where debug symbols are easy to apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but lldb does have a setting to stop on shared library loads:

```
(lldb) settings set target.process.stop-on-sharedlibrary-events 1
```

which will cause the program lldb is debugging to stop when a new shared library gets loaded.  Not much goes on in the process before the first shared library load, so this will catch it pretty early on.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Stopping at such an early stage is useful to set breakpoints on later functions.

Comment: How to remove this settings if set? It's getting stopped every time without running.

Comment: Got it just making it to 1 to 0 and running the command. solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can put lldb Xcode-specific setting commands in *~/.lldbinit-Xcode* file and they will only apply to lldb instances called from Xcode.

This helps keeping separate settings.

From [lldb(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/lldb.1.html):

> FILES
>
> lldb will read settings/aliases/commands from three files at
>   startup, if they exist.
>
> First, it will read a ~/.lldbinit-debugger command file.  If you are
>   using the lldb command line interface, this is ~/.lldbinit-lldb.  If
>   you are using lldb inside a GUI debugger like Xcode this will be
>   ~/.lldbinit-Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Entirely doable, at least under Xcode 7.

In an existing Xcode project, create a new schema. In the schema settings, under "Run", specify "Other executable" and choose the one you want. In schema properties, you may also specify command line, working directory, custom environment, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Neither `target.process.stop-on-sharedlibrary-events` nor `settings show target.process.stop-on-exec` was having the desired effect for me.

Starting at the very bottom of the stack, I saw `_dyld_start`, `dyldbootstrap::start`, and `dyld::_main`.

Creating a symbolic breakpoint for `dyld::_main`, specifying the module as `dyld`, worked for me to get the debugger very early in the startup process.

Trying to set breakpoints on the first two functions did not work for me. I believe that may have something to do with [dyld rebasing itself](https://github.com/apple-opensource-mirror/dyld/blob/609d6a3837257f70e4e2b10d6a342ed26c5a7077/src/dyldInitialization.cpp#L468-L505) inside that second function: the code isn’t running where the debugger expects it to be in memory until the third frame.